# How can I connect to a Mongodb database using Mongoose in NextJs13?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, routes, next.js, next.js13

I'm trying to build a Crud application with NextJS and MongoDB but I'm finding it difficult to connect to the database using mongoose. after trying the codes to connect to the db I keep getting this error.

image of error:
[image]

Module parse failed: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)

`Error: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)`

This is my code image of db connection code
[image]

Whenever I call the function on my route, I get that error message.
image of where i'm call the function
[image]

I have changed the connection code but it's still the same error